# how can i write Static Json Object in Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular2-forms

Here i have classes file

```
export class Emp{
EmpId:number;
EmpName:String,
EmpSal:string
}
```

How can i wrote static object Like EmpId=1,EmpNamw=john,Empsal=200
EmpId=2,EmpName=smith,EmpSal=300

Comment: Did you read the ‘getting started’ guide? http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html

Answer (score 5):

Typescript doesn't work like that. Its module based. You should export a let or const

in your case it would be

```
export let Emp = { 
    EmpId: 2,
    EmpName: 'Bla',
    EmpSal: 'Bla',
}
```

Comment: Dude. Why is Typescript like this?

Answer (score 2):

I used an interface to create a list of Emp objects and JSON.stringify to get them as a JSON string (you can see the result in the jsfiddle).

I guess you try to do something like this:

```
interface IEmp{
    EmpId:number;
    EmpName:string;
    EmpSal:string;
}

let emp1 : IEmp = {EmpId:1, EmpName:'name1', EmpSal:'sal1'};
let emp2 : IEmp = {EmpId:2, EmpName:'name2', EmpSal:'sal2'};

let lstEmp : Array<IEmp> = [emp1, emp2];

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(lstEmp);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kkxw1y0k/

Comment: Please explain what you are doing in this code, don't just paste code.

Comment: I used an interface to create a list of Emp objects and JSON.stringify to get them as a JSON string (you can see the result in the jsfiddle)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!